# Realm Swift SUBQUERY について

Tags: ios, swift, realm

よろしくお願いします。
iOS 8.0
Swift 2.1
Realm 0.96.3

親子関係を持つ二つのクラスを定義し、status が true の Child を一つ以上持つ Parent を抽出したいと思っています。

```
class Child: Object {
    dynamic var status = false
    dynamic var name = ""
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Parent: Object {
    let children = List<Child>()
    dynamic var name = ""
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setSampleData()
        procedure()
    }

    func procedure() {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(children, $c, $c.status == true).@count > 0")
        print(realm.objects(Parent).filter(predicate).description)
    }

    func setSampleData() {
        try! realm.write {
            self.realm.deleteAll()
            let parent1 = Parent(name: "Parent1")
            let parent2 = Parent(name: "Parent2")
            let parent3 = Parent(name: "Parent3")
            let child1  = Child(name:  "Child1")
            let child2  = Child(name:  "Child2")
            let child3  = Child(name:  "Child3")
            let child4  = Child(name:  "Child4")
            let child5  = Child(name:  "Child5")
            self.realm.add(parent1)
            self.realm.add(parent2)
            self.realm.add(parent3)
            self.realm.add(child1)
            self.realm.add(child2)
            self.realm.add(child3)
            self.realm.add(child4)
            self.realm.add(child5)
            child1.status = false
            child2.status = true
            child3.status = false
            child4.status = true
            child5.status = false
            parent1.children.append(child1)
            parent1.children.append(child2)
            parent2.children.append(child3)
            parent2.children.append(child4)
            parent3.children.append(child5)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

ビルドは成功しますが、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate expressions', reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'

SUBQUERYについて理解ができていないと思いますが、
調べてもなかなかわかりません。
どなたかアドバイスを頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

RealmでSubqueryはまだ利用できません。

それはさておき、「`status`が`true`の`Child`を一つ以上持つ`Parent`を抽出」ということであれば、もっと簡単に下記のコードで実現できます。

例のコードと一緒に実行すると、`parent1`と`parent2`を返します。（`parent3`は`status`が`false`の`Child`を持つだけなので除かれる）

これで回答になっていますでしょうか？

```
let parents = realm.objects(Parent).filter("ANY children.status == true")
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
私のやりたいことはできました。

RealmでSubqueryはまだ利用できないとのことですが、
[チートシート][cheatsheet]にはSubqueryの記述があります。
これはObjective-Cでは利用できるということでしょうか。

        [cheatsheet]: https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: @user13537 NSPredicateはCoreDataやNSArrayなどに対しても使われる汎用的なクエリを表すAPIなので、チートシートにはRealmでサポートされていないクエリの記述についても記載されています。このチートシートはRealmに限ったものではなくて、（CoreDataなどで使われることも想定した）NSPredicate自体のチートシートです。その上で、Realmがサポートしている記述につきましては、左にピンクの丸いドットを表示しています。サブクエリの箇所にはそのピンクのドットが付いてないので、未対応ということになります。